# Notify when control centre/Notification centre appears in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, controls, nsnotificationcenter

I want to be notified when Notification center/Control center/Calls opens up while app is running. *applicationWillResignActive* is not specific. It gets called even when homebutton is tapped twice.

Comment: can't you use API to be hit on didReceiveRemoteNotification method? btw you cannot have access to get notifications due to sandboxing or you can search for any third party for this.

Comment: may this link will be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html